# Windows HtmlHelp popup on wrong monitor

Tags: windows, winapi, chm

I'm using the HTMLHelp function with C to provide short, context sensitive help for the edit fields on various dialogs.  It works perfectly **except** when the dialog is located on a monitor whose screen has negative X coordinates.

For example, I have **three** monitors and the top, left point on the CENTER  of the three is the (0,0) point on the screen.  That makes ALL X-coordinates on the LEFT screen have negative values.  When I call HTMLHelp for HH_DISPLAY_TEXT_POPUP, the tooltip it displays shows up stuck to the left edge of the CENTER screen instead of on the LEFT screen, where it belongs.  When the coordinate for the help popup is on the center or right screens, the popup is exactly where it should be.

Does anyone know a way to get the HTMLHelp function to work correctly and just use the given coordinates instead of applying an invalid range check and "fixing" my X location?

If not, I guess I will be forced to write my own version of a help popup function, but I'd much rather use the system feature.

Comment: How do you call context-sensitive help in your application? What programming language / platform you are using (C, I added in the body because tag was deleted)?

Comment: In the multi-monitor universe, many programs stop working. There are a lot of issues involved in generalizing a uni-monitor application to run on multi-monitor systems. Following link [Virtual Screen Coordinates](http://www.flounder.com/virtual_screen_coordinates.htm) I found will not attempt to address all of those issues. The essay is going to concentrate on just one aspect of multi-monitor programming, the virtual screen coordinate system.

Comment: I'm fully aware of multi-monitor issues as I've had to ensure *MY* software works OK in those situations.  I believe I have a reasonable expectation that the operating system vendor who added multi-monitor support to their OS and who created the built-in help functions would provide tools that work correctly in their own system.  However, since they didn't bother to do that, I was wondering if there was a work-around, or perhaps some other package -- that works correctly, and is as simple to use -- might be available.